# Installshield LE with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: installshield-le

I am trying to build an ASP.NET MVC installation using installshield LE with VS.NET 2012. I have chosen the solution configuration manager to SingleImage and trying to build the project. I have a UAT web.config transformation in place. After installation web.config in the installed folder is empty. How can I force the installation to pick up the right web.config file while packaging.Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

-George

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

In your Msbuild command you want the

Target=Package
and Configuration="Release"

This way it will use the Config transform you specify..

Also you will need to then add the config file through dynamic linking in the install shield.

Comment: It is unclear to me. Could you please elaborate on how to force it to use web.config without changing its contents?

Comment: you shouldn't need to change the config file once it is working in debug mode for example. The msbuild will look after the transform.. i THINK thats what your question means.. For example:
`msbuild solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;_PackageTempDir=..\publishFolder`

The only potential issue really is surrounding the connection strings : Take a look here : [MS BUILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx)